# alias method - for n discrete values, should the table size be n-1 or n?

Tags: probability, distributions, simulation

I'm looking at various proofs and implementations of the alias method, and in some they use n bins: [darts-dice-coins](https://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/), and in some n-1 bins: [Ross](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/introduction-to-probability-model-s.ross-math-cs.blog_.ir_.pdf) - see page 691, 11.4.1. Note that the bins in Ross's are noted $Q^{(i)}$ - so that a n-vector distribution $P$ would be represented by $n-1$ distributions $Q$.

are these 2 exactly the same? why would you want to use an $n-1$ when it's so natural to use $n$?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "use" here.  Your second reference Ross explicitly involves $n$ probabilities, so there is no difference whatsoever in the meanings of $n$ between the two references.  The only difference is the first one indexes values from $0$ through $n-1$ while Ross uses $1$ through $n.$

Comment: @whuber - I'm sorry but I disagree. there's an explicit difference here. Note that for a 4-values vector Ross creates 3 Q distributions, each summing to $\frac{1}{3}$, while Keith creates 4 bins, each summing to $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Read the Keith's "Proving Alias Tables Exist" section and notice in his example, with $n=4,$ that the fractions all have $n-1=3$ for the denominator.  Read further down to his pseudo-coded algorithm.  In the "initialization" stage notice the loop goes "for $j=1$ to $n-1.$"  The two sources use "$n$" in the same way.

Comment: @whuber - with the deepest respect, I still do not agree with you. the fractions have 3 in the denominator just as an example, he's still checking if they are below or above 0.25, NOT 0.33 as opposed to Ross. In the initialization he is multiplying by n and comparing to 1, and creating a n-sized table for a n-sized probability... can you please un-close my question and let someone else see it? in light of your previous answers and reputation there's 99% that you're right and I'm blind, but I'm still not convinced...

Comment: Everybody can see your question--it is not hidden.

Comment: btw, the reason keith's loop goes only from 1 to n-1 is that the last bin must have weight=1, see stage 4